# Random unique ids

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to generate something like 6B6E23518 using randomString() which I'm calling inside my controller

```
 function randomString($chars=10) //generate random string
{
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randstring = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $chars; $i++) {
        $randstring .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }
    return $randstring;
}

public function store(TicketsCreateRequest $request)
{
    $ticket = $user->tickets()->create([

            'ticket_hash' => $this->randomString(10),
            // ....


    ]);
}
```

but this keeps on storing 0 into 'ticket_hash'  and nothing gets generated??

Comment: What is the type of database column `ticket_hash`?

Comment: it was an integer type and changed it to varchar and it works now .

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your source code, is `randomString()` a public method of your controller class or is it a global function declared elsewhere outside of the class? I ask because it's entered above without the `public` visibility qualifier and with slightly different indentation to the method below it.

If this function is not an instanace method of your class, then your call to `$this->randomString()` is probably not calling the method you're expecting it to call. If your `randomString()` function is a global function defined elsewhere you should call it directly (eg. `'ticket_hash' => randomString(10),`)

*For what it's worth*, for random strings like this it might be best to use the Laravel framework's `Str` class, only because it may be more stable and is definitely more widely used.

The [Str::random()](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Support/Str.html#method_random) method achieves the output you're looking for in this case.

Comment: it is a method within the store method , currently I'm using str_pad(mt_rand(1,99999999),8,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT) but i need to add more combination of ids and chars

Answer (score 0):

column ticket_hash was an integer type ,changed it to varchar and it works now.